# Get average daily rate of commits per each user in git

Tags: git

I need to get a list of all users with their average rate of commits per day.

For example:

```
Ashraf Bashir 1.6
Barack Obama 2.4
Albert Einstein 0.7
Tom Cruise 1.3
```

Which command in git may do this ?

Comment: You can start from here: `git shortlog -ns` (prints users and commits but without averaging). Taken from https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras

Comment: I would love to see Tom's commit history

Answer (score 2):

`git shortlog -sn` gives the number of commits they have made,

you may need something similar to https://sites.google.com/site/alturin2/gsoc2008 to get what you need though